# PreventDefault inside JSONP callback

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I would like to use the event's preventDefault method inside jsonp's callback. I must use pure javascript. I already have a function that emulates jsonp request. Here's what im doing:

```
var evt_temp = null;

function onContextMenu(event)
{    
    evt_temp = event;
    jsonp
    ({
        url: "someurl",
        params: "someparams",
        callback: "cb"
    });
}

function cb(response)
{
    if (something == true)
    {
        evt_temp.preventDefault();
        evt_temp = null;
    }
}
```

My solution worked, but i feel like it's not a good idea, store the event on a var. Anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: Your jsonp API is horrible, fix it so it takes a function reference not a function name

Comment: You probably dont know what JSONP is to make a comment like that... The only way to make a jsonp request is like that: http://url?callback=method. You MUST send your callback function as string.

Comment: Of course I know that, but that's magic that can be done in the jsonp function, why can't jsonp accept a callback function then create a global uuid store the callback there and then do `url?callback=globaluuid`

Comment: Well, my question is: how doing that will resolve my problem? My jsonp api is horrible but it works. Make it accept a annonymous function wont solve my problem. I cant send an object to jsonp request then respond it on the callback function. If its possible i have never seen that.

Comment: See answer. It's not hard to do this under the hood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thats how i made it, in case of someone need some day:

```
var MyAPI =
{
    jsonp: function(args)
    {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        var url = args.url + "?";
        var generatedFunction = "jsonpCallback" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000001);

        window[generatedFunction] = function(response)
        {
            args.callback(eval("(" + response + ")"));
            delete window[generatedFunction];
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(generatedFunction));
        };

        if (args.params)
        {
            url += "_r={";

            for (var prop in args.params)
            {
                url += "\"" + prop + "\":\"" + args.params[prop] + "\",";
            }

            url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);
            url += "}&"
        }

        url += "_cb=" + generatedFunction;

        script.src = url;
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.id = generatedFunction;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
};
```

Calling it:

```
MyAPI.jsonp
({
    url: "someurl",
    params: { param1: "param1", param2: "param2" },
    callback: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Its nothing against it, but in your case it seems a bit useless.  As you use an asynchron callback, `preventDefault()` will called after the default browser behavior was happen. It only make sense when you use it directly in the callback function of the event.

Comment: Its not useless. I need to show a custom menu on the right click on  some links in a site. When i right click a link (oncontextmenu event) i send a jsonp request (cuz its cross domain) and i should only show my custom menu (and stop the event of contextmenu) in certain cases (according to the jsonp response). Otherwise i should do the normal behavior. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onContextMenu(event) {    
    evt_temp = event;
    good_jsonp({
        url: "someurl",
        params: "someparams",
        callback: function (response) {
            if (something === true) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}

var good_jsonp = (function () {
    var uuid = 0;
    return good_jsonp;

    function good_jsonp(obj) {
        var id = "good_jsonp" + ++uuid;
        window[id] = obj.callback;
        obj.callback = id;
        jsonp(obj);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Your answer is not full but it gave me a good start to how make it. Thanks.